# Conditional creation of a dataframe column based on numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe timeseries (of about 1000 rows and the four columns below) that looks like this:

```
Date          Values  Avg    +1 Stdev
01/01/2010    1.01    1.00   1.05
02/01/2010    1.02    1.00   1.05
03/01/2010    1.04    1.00   1.05
04/01/2010    -0.97   1.00   1.05
05/01/2010    1.12    1.00   1.05
06/01/2010    1.08    1.00   1.05
....
```

What I'm trying to do is create a fifth column (called 'Trigger Date'), where if the value in column 2 breaches the threshold set in column 4, then the new column returns the date (from the index column), otherwise no value is returned. 
The additional constraint here is that the fifth column should ALSO NOT return a date if the previous value already breached the threshold in column 4.

In other words, the psuedocode for the problem would be:

```
If df['Values'] > df['+1 Stdev']
AND
If df['Values'] (for the row above) < df['+1 Stdev']
THEN
Return df['Date'] in new column df['Trigger Date']
ELSE
Leave row in df['Trigger Date'] blank
```

Any help on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Additional question - any way to add a third constraint, where no trigger date is returned if one has already occurred in the past XX days (eg in the past 30 days)? So expected would look like:

```
         Date  Values  Avg  +1 Stdev Trigger Date
0  01/01/2010    1.01  1.0      1.05          NaN
1  02/01/2010    1.02  1.0      1.05          NaN
2  03/01/2010    1.04  1.0      1.05          NaN
3  04/01/2010   -0.97  1.0      1.05          NaN
4  05/01/2010    1.12  1.0      1.05   05/01/2010
5  06/01/2010    1.08  1.0      1.05          NaN
6  07/01/2010    1.03  1.0      1.05          NaN
7  08/01/2010    1.07  1.0      1.05          NaN <- above threshold, but trigger occurred within last 30 days so don't return date
...
50 20/02/2010    1.12  1.0      1.05          20/02/2010 <- more than 30 days later, no trigger dates in between, so return date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for values above row:

```
m1 = df['Values'] > df['+1 Stdev']
m2 = df['Values'].shift() < df['+1 Stdev']

df['Trigger Date'] = np.where(m1 & m2, df['Date'], np.nan)
print (df)
         Date  Values  Avg  +1 Stdev Trigger Date
0  01/01/2010    1.01  1.0      1.05          NaN
1  02/01/2010    1.02  1.0      1.05          NaN
2  03/01/2010    1.04  1.0      1.05          NaN
3  04/01/2010   -0.97  1.0      1.05          NaN
4  05/01/2010    1.12  1.0      1.05   05/01/2010
5  06/01/2010    1.08  1.0      1.05          NaN
```

EDIT:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

m1 = df['Values'] > df['+1 Stdev']
m2 = df['Values'].shift() < df['+1 Stdev']
a = df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')
L = [df['Date'].shift(-1).isin(pd.date_range(x, y, freq='d')) for x, y in zip(a, df['Date'] )]
m3 = np.logical_or.reduce(L)

mask = (m1 & m2) | ~m3

df.loc[mask, 'Trigger Date'] = df['Date']
print (df)
        Date  Values  Avg  +1 Stdev Trigger Date
0 2010-01-01    1.01  1.0      1.05          NaT
1 2010-01-02    1.02  1.0      1.05          NaT
2 2010-01-03    1.04  1.0      1.05          NaT
3 2010-01-04   -0.97  1.0      1.05          NaT
4 2010-01-05    1.12  1.0      1.05   2010-01-05
5 2010-01-06    1.08  1.0      1.05          NaT
6 2010-02-20    1.12  1.0      1.05   2010-02-20
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I needed to do - thanks! One additional question, if I wanted to add an additional filter (m3) where no trigger date is returned if one has already occurred in the past 30 days, any idea how I would do that?

Comment: @KUpadhyay - Is possible add sample data with expected output?

Comment: @KUpadhyay - I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can't type out code in comment, but eg if row 6 has value 1.03 (below threshold), then row 7 has value 1.07 (above threshold), any way to NOT return a date for row 7 as a trigger already happened within the last 30 days? but then if row 50 is 1.12 (above threshold) then a date SHOULD be returned?

Comment: @KUpadhyay - I think you can change sample data in question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54159953/edit)

Comment: Edited the original question

Comment: @KUpadhyay - More complicated, please check edited answer.